# Dynamic data needing to store as JSON stringify with LocalStorage in AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have app in angularjs 1.5.x  that i save dynamically db driven question answers to localstorage .   Currently i'm doing it without a JSON format,  which i don't like

```
.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            set: function (key, value) {
                return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
            },
            get: function (key) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            },
            destroy: function (key) {
                return localStorage.removeItem(key);
            },
        };
    }]);
```

While this "works"  it end up then with my hard-coding answers that have dynamic questions and it not being in JSON makes it hard to then make DECISIONS into the next question

```
sessionService.set('agentid', agent.agentid);
```

**See how that ends up being one of 50 answers and it would be great to just ADD and UPDATE to a JSON object and Stringify it to localStorage ...**

How can i do that?

Comment: Same principal. Keep a bigger object or array in your service. Whenever an update event occurs (user initiated for example) ... just call a method in service that stringifies and stores the whole array/object in one storage key location

Comment: So, to clarify... You want to add  and update items to a JSON stored in localsotrage? Don't you? I think that you have to save whole array instead of each item id...

Comment: Do you have a better solution than what the other guy suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just keep a copy of the json in ram ?

```
.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function ($http) {

var temp = {};

    return {
        set: function (value) {
            temp = value;
            return localStorage.setItem("json_key", JSON.stringify(temp));
        },
        get: function () {
            temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("json_key"));
            return temp;
        },
        destroy: function (key) {
            return localStorage.removeItem("json_key");
        },
        update: function(key, value) {
            temp.key = value;
            set(temp);
            return temp;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here "json_key" is the string key for getting the value in the localStorage.

temp is the ram copy at any moment of the local storage.

You can init temp with get.

update return the new value.

value should be the new json (I mean the whole json you want to store).