# How to store the dynamic Json values in a single key using localstorage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

I want to store the local-storage data in node.js, I have created two servers. one for call server and another one server for getting transcription. In that call server, I want to store the caller information and another server for storing corresponded transcription details for that call using local-storage.

I have set and get the local-storage data and clear the data is fine for the single call. while the first call is in progress, I made a second call scenario the local-storage data gets overridden.

How to resolve this case ?? is there any possibility to store and retrieve the call details in a single local-storge data??? I want to get both call details simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep a copy of the json in ram ?

```
.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function ($http) {

var temp = {};

    return {
        set: function (value) {
            temp = value;
            return localStorage.setItem("json_key", JSON.stringify(temp));
        },
        get: function () {
            temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("json_key"));
            return temp;
        },
        destroy: function (key) {
            return localStorage.removeItem("json_key");
        },
        update: function(key, value) {
            temp.key = value;
            set(temp);
            return temp;
        }
    };
}]);
```

from here .

[Dynamic data needing to store as JSON stringify with LocalStorage in AngularJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023605/dynamic-data-needing-to-store-as-json-stringify-with-localstorage-in-angularjs-p)

Comment: can I use this method in node.js